# Characteristic polynomial for the rank-$1$ perturbation

Tags: matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

> Define 
>   $A=\operatorname{diag}\{a_i\}$. Introduce the polynomials
>   $$
> p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda-a_i),\qquad p_i(\lambda)=\frac{p(\lambda)}{\lambda-a_i}=\prod_{j\ne i}(\lambda-a_j),
> $$
>   and calculate the characteristic polynomial for the rank-one perturbation $A+bk^T$ using Sylvester's determinant theorem
>   \begin{align}
> \det(\lambda I-A-bk^T)=p(\lambda)(1-k^T(\lambda I-A)^{-1}b)=p(\lambda)-\sum_{i=1}^n k_ib_ip_i(\lambda).
> \end{align}

Can somebody please explain how did we get the last expression in the last row?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
p(\lambda)(\lambda I-A)^{-1}
=p(\lambda)\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda-a_1},\,\frac{1}{\lambda-a_2},\ldots,\frac{1}{\lambda-a_n}\right)
=\operatorname{diag}\left(p_1(\lambda),\,p_2(\lambda),\ldots,p_n(\lambda)\right),
$$
we have
$$
p(\lambda)k^T(\lambda I-A)^{-1}b
=k^T\operatorname{diag}\left(p_1(\lambda),\,p_2(\lambda),\ldots,p_n(\lambda)\right)b
=\sum_ik_ib_ip_i(\lambda).
$$